# how to use hashes by calling the value in perl

Tags: perl

I'm currently writing a script to check the existance of files reside in several directories.  I'm writing in hash and plan to assign same numeric number to those directories that need to perform same subroutines. And thus I'll call by the value names.  In the other words, those directories match the value will do same subroutine else it will be dump into a list so that it will be print out in summary later.  I'm writing the script as below but it seem doesn't perform correctly as mit seem doesn't capture the value at all.  May I know where goes wrong here?  Note I want to call the hash by value but not key.

```
my %hashDir = (dirA => 1, dirB => 2, dirC =>3 , dirD => 1, dirE =>2, dirF =>1);
my $key = "";
my $value = "" ;
my $buf ;
my $d = "$basedir/$buf";

while (($key, $value) = each (%hashDir)) {
    if (exists $hashDir{'1'}) {
        print "test1\n" ;
        subroutine1() ;
    } elsif (exists $hashDir{'2'}) {
        print "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" ;
        subroutine2() ;
    } else {
        $missingdir .= "\"$buf\" " ;
        print "test3\n" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also fixed your indentation.

Comment: What value does $basedir have? Where do you assign a value to $buf?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand how to access elements in a hash. When you do `exists $hashDir{'1'}`, you're looking to see if `'1'` is a key in the hash. It is not. I think you want to do:

```
if ($hashDir{$key} == 1)
```

or since you already have the value,

```
if ($value == 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm newbie in Perl, you're right, probably I need to use "if ($hashDir{$key} == 1) ".  I was thinkking if I can use the "exist" to check for the dir so that I can filter out those not in the hash in summary and to use the key to identify the subroutine.  Am I choosing right way to do by hash?  Thanks.

Comment: Well no, you'll only get ones in the hash in the first place, that's what the while (...each...) does, if it isn't in the hash you won't get it

Comment: But do use the second one there, you're already setting $value = $hashDir{$key} in the while (...) so you shouldn't bother accessing the hash again, just use $value.

Comment: And the way to check if a file exist is `if -e $file`. But the problem statement is quite unclear.

Comment: Do you mean just do : if ($hashDir{$key} == 1) {
  do something.... } elsif ($hashDir{$key} == 2) {
  do something ;
 } else {
  print "test3\n" ;

Comment: Sorry for the confusions.  My intention is to do this:  I have a predefined list of directories to check, namely dirA, dirB, dirC, etc... And my script will ask user to keyin the path which will have/or have not directories as the predefine list.

Comment: SO I'll need to check the existance of the directories: if dir exists, then it will execute something; else it will need to be listed down as dir not exist.  For the dir which exist, it will be category to several group, those in th esame group will need to perform same subroutine, that's why comes into my mind to use the hash to check for existance dir as well as to use the value to identify which group is the directory belong to.  Can someone pls show me sample script that what I can do here... I'm kinda lost in direction, really new in Perl.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I finally manage to use the if ($value ==1) ... etc to call and understand the logic behind.. Thanks Dan and those who have spend time on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use meaningful names rather than $key/$value.

Use a "dispatch table" to decide what subroutine to call.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter path to top-level directory: ";
chomp(my $basedir = <STDIN>);
chdir $basedir or die "could not cd to '$basedir' $!";

my %hashDir = (
    dirA => 1,
    dirB => 2,
    dirC => 3,
    dirD => 1,
    dirE => 2,
    dirF => 1,
);

my %dispatch = (
    1 => \&subroutine1,
    2 => \&subroutine2,
    3 => \&subroutine3,
);

my @missing;
while ( my($dir, $group) = each (%hashDir) ){
    if (-d $dir) {
        $dispatch{$group}->($dir);
    }
    else {
        push @missing, $dir;
    }
}

print 'Missing dirs: ', join(', ', @missing), "\n" if @missing;

sub subroutine1 { warn "subroutine1() got called for $_[0] directory\n" }
sub subroutine2 { warn "subroutine2() got called for $_[0] directory\n" }
sub subroutine3 { warn "subroutine3() got called for $_[0] directory\n" }
```